# Wubi.exe is not in Xubuntu 14.04 Disks. Can someone help me install Xubuntu1404 with Wubi

Tags: xubuntu, wubi

The Wubi.exe is on the Ubuntu 1404 disk, not on Xubuntu1404 disk; (and when you launch it supports Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu), **but... doesnt support Xubuntu. Can anyone provide guidance? Thanks so much!**

Comment: Thanks Charles. When you launch wubi.exe it allows you to select from the dropdown "Lubuntu, Kubuntu, ..." etc... But it doesnt have Xubuntu in the list. Can anyone provide guidance?

Comment: The Xubuntu folks decided they didn't want to support Wubi so it was removed from the choices. You could try and install 14.04 and then download the Xubuntu desktop. However, their are issues in installing 14.04. Wubi is currently not downloading the iso - it hangs. You can download it yourself and put it next to wubi, but then there is a bug in the MD5 check so you have to open and command shell and do "wubi --skipmd5check" but then you run into another bug that is discussed in a forum and here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIKf_uM9FHI. It may be best with Wubi to use 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229766  for the forum staff recommendations on WUBI.   It really is not for 14.04 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The Xubuntu folks decided they didn't want to support Wubi so it was removed from the choices. You could try and install 14.04 and then download the Xubuntu desktop. However, there are issues in installing 14.04. Wubi is currently not downloading the iso - it hangs / freezes / stalls. You can download it yourself via a torrent client or download manager or your browser and put it next to wubi.exe in a separate directory. But then there is a bug in the MD5 check that was introduced either in 12.10 or after 12.10, so you have to open a command shell and do "wubi --skipmd5check". This mostly works,  but then you run into another bug that is discussed in an [Ubuntu support forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218439) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIKf_uM9FHI). It may be best with Wubi to use 12.04.